# Alocação dinâmica e tempo de execução de funções

Tags: c, funções, alocação, lista-encadeada

Quando utilizamos alguma das funções de alocação dinâmica em C (malloc, calloc, realloc etc), dentro de uma função que é chamada pela main, a memória permanecerá alocada ao final da execução dessa função ou será automaticamente desalocada? Caso a memória permaneça alocada, como devo proceder para "manusear" esse espaço de memória alocado anteriormente fora da função?

Utilizando o código abaixo, por exemplo, eu preciso utilizar a lista encadeada que eu criei em adicionar() na main

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct celula{
    int n;
    struct celula *next;
};

typedef struct celula cel;

void adicionar();

int main ()
{
    adicionar();
}

void adicionar()
{
    cel *p, *p2, *aux;
    int adc, x;

    p = NULL;

    printf("Deseja adicionar elementos na lista? \n 1- Sim \n 2- Nao \n");
    scanf("%d", &adc);

    if(adc == 1)
    {
        do
        {
            p2 = malloc(sizeof(cel));

            printf("Digite o valor que deseja adicionar \n");
            scanf("%d", &x);

            p2->n = x;
            p2->next = p;

            p = p2;

            printf("Deseja adicionar elementos na lista? \n 1- Sim \n 2- Nao \n");
            scanf("%d", &adc);

        }while(adc == 1);
    }

    aux = p;

    while(aux != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", aux->n);
        aux = aux->next;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A memória realmente continua alocada ao fim da execução da função. Para limpá-la use `free`, como já foi dito pelo @Rodrigo Vieira.
Para conseguir manipular os elementos alocados na memória dentro da `main` existem duas alternativas. Declarar um ponteiro global do tipo `cel` e fazer ele apontar para `p` dentro da função `adicionar`, ou, o que eu acho mais viável para não interferir muito na atual implementação, mudar o tipo da função adicionar para `cel*` e retornar o ponteiro `p`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct celula{
    int n;
    struct celula *next;
};

typedef struct celula cel;

    int main ()
    {

        cel *p = adicionar();

    }

    cel *adicionar()
    {
        cel *p, *p2, *aux;
        int adc, x;

        p = NULL;

        printf("Deseja adicionar elementos na lista? \n 1- Sim \n 2- Nao \n");
        scanf("%d", &adc);

        if(adc == 1)
        {
            do
            {
                p2 = malloc(sizeof(cel));

                printf("Digite o valor que deseja adicionar \n");
                scanf("%d", &x);

                p2->n = x;
                p2->next = p;

                p = p2;

                printf("Deseja adicionar elementos na lista? \n 1- Sim \n 2- Nao \n");
                scanf("%d", &adc);

            }while(adc == 1);
        }

        aux = p;

        while(aux != NULL)
        {
            printf("%d ", aux->n);
            aux = aux->next;
        }
        return p;

    }
```

Assim pode usar o `p` de dentro da `main` como a "cabeça" da sua lista.

Answer (score 2):

Ela continua alocada sim, para liberar você precisa utilizar o free.

Você precisa passar como ponteiro de ponteiro.

```
void adicionar(cel** c)
{
}
```

Caso tenha alocado na main e queira apenas alterar alguma propriedade  basta passar como ponteiro (*).

Agora se quer alocar dentro da função precisa passar ponteiro de ponteiro (**).

Segue um exemplo:

```
typedef struct aluno{
char *nome;
char *curso; } aluno;

void aloca_aluno(aluno **a,int t);

int main()
{
 aluno *a = NULL;
 aloca_aluno(&a, 1);
 return 0;
}
void aloca_aluno(aluno **a,int t)
{
   //Usando realloc para não perder caso já esteja alocado algo
  if((*a=(aluno*)realloc(*a,t*sizeof(aluno)))==NULL)
  {
   //Não conseguir alocar
     exit(1);
  }
 }
```